# Include non ejs files in ejs template engine

Tags: node.js, express, include, template-engine, ejs

Is it posible to add files that dont have the .ejs ending when using the ejs template engine with node.js and express?

I want to put shaders in seperate files with .glsl ending for example. Than I want to include them like this:

```
<% include /shaders/example.vertex.glsl %>
```

If I use example.vertex.glsl.ejs it works, but than syntax highlighting for shaders is not working anymore...

I am actually not bound to ejs. Any other express templating engine this would work in is fine. I just used ejs because I worked with it already a little bit beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as long as you tell the express what engine should be used to process the extension with [app.engine(ext, callback)](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.engine).

Set the following before your routes somewhere:

```
app.engine('glsl', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

Then your includes such as `<% include /shaders/example.vertex.glsl %>` will work fine. These are processed in the same way as ejs files then, so as well as the include working as you describe, you can also put inline `<%=variableFromNode%>` type stuff in the included glsl files and it will process that too.